# Does a System with Absolutely no Soldered Antennas Exist?

Tags: wifi, desktop, security, home-security

I need a system with absolutely no wireless capabilities for my small business that will solely operate through a wired LAN. Since I have no need for WiFi or Bluetooth, I’d prefer not having to deal with contigencies stemming from possible unauthorized wireless injections or WiFi packet sniffers. I’m not willing to simply turn these wireless signals off through my system, because I for one know, there exists many firms which have stringent rules against the use of WiFi chips within their mainframes. Thus, I’m just not content with having any sort of antenna within my system. I’m currently considering getting a chrome box because I won’t need the system for any hardcore applications, but simply an internet connection. Any useful resources would be helpful.

Comment: Could you define "system"? I guess you mean a laptop or tablet computer, right?

Comment: There are plenty of these systems. Are you looking for something that's actually hardened though, or just don't want it to have wireless?

Comment: I’d prefer it not having any wireless capabilities. Preferably one with no antennas already soldered in which would also exclude the WiFi adapter card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me clean up the question a bit as I understand it first; you want a device that will give you internet capabilities for a browser and possibly some other applications (but mostly the browser).  It cannot have a wireless network interface component because you are concerned with infringing on company policies regarding wireless access within their networks (a mainframe is a very different thing and has nothing to do with wireless networking).

Before I answer, I'd like to point out that any company worth anything at all has abandoned the practice of forbidding wireless devices, as cell phones exist and are microcomputers with wireless network accessibility.  Any company with which you'd want to associate will have a modern philosophy about cybersecurity and prohibit unauthorized connections technologically so you don't have to worry about it.

You will be hard-pressed to find a notebook computer that doesn't have wireless LAN access.  Most motherboards have them *built in* and your only option to disable them is via the BIOS, which is effectively a secure way to make the machine behave as if it has no wireless card at all (since a BIOS hack is not a realistic problem).  All Chromebooks have WLAN access components.  Most laptops do not possess a normal network jack anymore and you'll need to get an external RJ45 port on a USB dongle to use physical networking lines.

Since laptops simply aren't made without WLAN capability anymore, your only option other than just disabling it yourself is to physically remove it yourself.  Some Dell Latitude and HP models have the card (the size of a small cracker) in a slot on the motherboard with two screws holding it down and antennae that lead to the monitor.  Disconnect the antennae wires, wrap their contacts in electrical tape, and remove the card.